# Any way to force TortoiseGit (or any other Git software) to treat Symbolic Links (in Windows) as real files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, git, tortoise-git

- OS: Win10

In Windows (by most Git software, however, I'd like to emphasize on TortoiseGit) **Hard Symbolic Link** is treated as regular file. However, **Soft Symlinks** are being ignored - Git software can't version the file content or detect changes.

Is there any way, that Soft Symlinks were also treated same way ? I have marked checkbox (during Git-Scm installation) to enable symlink support, but it doesn't address soft-symlinks as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note on terminology.  A *symbolic link* is equivalent to a *soft link*; a *hard link* is separate and is not considered to be a type of symbolic link.

The problem you're having is that while you've enabled symlinks for Git, Windows chose to make working with symbolic links require elevated privileges by default.  As such, you'll need to either adjust the permissions on your repository, or, in Windows 10, enable Developer Mode and reboot so that you can create symbolic links.  Once you've done that, you can set `git config core.symlinks true` (*`git config --global`* to adjust it globally) and then check out a new revision, and if you've enabled Developer Mode, any future repositories you clone or create should support symbolic links properly.

Comment: can you please mention, how/where *"adjust the permissions on your repository"* can be done? specific `git` command or option in GUI? (I couldn't locate any option in General/Advanced)

Comment: second question - I do have enabled symlinks from LocalPolicies, and I am able to create symlinks/hardlinks normally, and is it detrimental to also enable  `developer mode` to achieve that? I am trying to avoid enabling dev.mode

Comment: I cannot speak to how to set Windows permissions, because I don't use Windows.  I just know that elevated permissions are required.  I strongly suggest enabling Developer Mode unless you have a good reason not to since it unbreaks symlinks on the whole.